# Duplicate request to OData v2 service

Tags: sapui5

we have configured a descriptor (manifest.json) for our frontend application that is using an OData service as a data source with the following configurations:

```
            "": {
                "dataSource": "mainService",
                "preload": true,
                "settings": {
                    "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
                    "defaultCountMode": "Inline",
                    "refreshAfterChange": false,
                    "metadataUrlParams": {
                        "value-list": "none"
                    },
                    "useBatch": false
                }
            }
```

For some reason sporadically when the page is loading there are 2 identical OData requests and the first is immediately canceled. Have you observed similar behavior and have a solution for this? Thanks in advance!